# PHP Arrays duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => some lastname
        [address] => some address
        [product] => product 1
        [year] => 2013
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => some lastname 2
        [address] => some address 2
        [product] => product 2
        [year] => 2013
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => some lastname 3
        [address] => some address 3
        [product] => product 3
        [year] => 2013
    )
)
```

And second:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => some lastname 2
        [address] => some address 2
        [product] => product 2
        [year] => 2014
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => lastname
        [address] => address
        [product] => prod
        [year] => 2013
    )
)
```

I need combine two array to result like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lastname] => some lastname 2
        [address] => some address 2
        [product] => product 2
        [year] => 2014
    )
)
```

Lastname, addres, product is the same in array1 and array2 only diff is year.

Any idea how to create that result array in php?
I cant

Comment: Can you show us some code you have tried?

Comment: You should also consider adding some explaination on the algorithm : why should the program save this array with these value ? Why it not save for example _2013_ instead of _2014_ ? etc...

Comment: Use `array_uintersect` with some recursive array compare function

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand your question well, you can use array_intersect function.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just go over array2 items and search match in array1 and append it to result array

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array2 as $item2){

    foreach ($array1 as $item1){
        if($item1['lastname'] != $item2['lastname']) break;
        if($item1['address'] != $item2['address']) break;
        if($item1['product'] != $item2['product']) break;

        $result[] = $item2;
    }
}
```

in $result you will have all items with 2014 date